# I need to do a nslookup of the RDS instance address. What is the best way to do this via terraform?

Tags: terraform, nslookup

I need to do a nslookup of the RDS instance address. What is the best way to do this via terraform?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use an external data source. Here's a demo which shows how to use a bash script that uses `nslookup` to retrieve the IP address for `google.com`.

Given `util.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ip=$(nslookup "$1" | awk '/Server/ {print $2}')
jq -n --arg ip "$ip" '{"ip":$ip}'
```

and `main.tf`:

```
locals {
  host = "google.com"
}

data "external" "util" {
  program = ["bash","util.sh","${local.host}"]
}

output "ip" {
  value = data.external.util.result.ip
}
```

```bash
$ terraform apply -auto-approve
ip = "172.30.240.1"
```

Comment: I am yet to try this . I was trying to get around this by using the ` code `data "dns_a_record_set" "rds_proxy_endpoint" {
  host = var.rds_proxy_endpoint
}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need this information? You should never need to operate the IP address of your RDS because it's a managed service, and the IP address may change (service updates, failover), so it's safe to use its FQDN.

```
You can get FQDN from:
data "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  db_instance_identifier = "my-test-database"
}
```

as `data.aws_db_instance.database.address`

Comment: The IP address is needed to provide as a target to an NLB to create a VPC privatelink

Comment: I understand the IP address may change , hence I have used an RDS proxy in front of the RDS which ensure the IP remains static.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But still bad, because you are not triggering terraform if failover happened. Here is how AWS recommend to do, but hardly aligns with the Terraform :( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/access-amazon-rds-across-vpcs-using-aws-privatelink-and-network-load-balancer/